# Classical Guitar. How to study from fret 5 to 12

Tags: classical-guitar, sight-reading

I started learning to read music with a classical guitar. What I'm doing is to study the C scale from fret 0 to 4, and next I try to play a study based in that scale. So far, I have noted that most of the studies I have found, are composed to play notes between the frets 0 to 4. I wonder, when I finally master that section of the fretboard, how can I study the notes starting from fret 5 to 12? are there studies that concentrates the notes in that section of the fretboard (I haven't found a lot)?

The big question is: how do you study the note learning process from the fret 5 to 12?

Comment: Google Caged system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use the scales you already know, but shift the fretted notes down one string and up to the 5th fret but use the same open strings as always.

C Major Scale (C:V)

```
$6.8 $4.0 $5.7 8 $3.0 $4.7 $2.0 $3.5
```

---

You can see from this example that the fifth fret itself is only needed for one note, the upper C. So, the same technique can be applied to shifts up to the 7th fret. In this scale, of course, since the index finger is anchored at the seventh fret, all the fingerings shift by one and the first C is fretted with the second (middle) finger.

C Major Scale (C:VII)

```
$6.8 $4.0 $5.7 8 $3.0 $4.7 $2.0 $4.10
```

---

Another way is to practice scales on one string, shifting up five frets instead of shifting strings. To fret high up on the neck on a classical guitar without a cutaway, stick the tip of your thumb in the crack right where the neck and fretboard join the body, then you can reach all the upper register notes.

Answer (score 2):

I'd be inclined to use the same studies, but use position 1 of the C scale, which spans between 7th and 10th frets.The root C is on bottom string, 8th fret. On the lower strings, you'll play exactly the same notes as starting on 5th st, 3rd fret. As much as possible, try to keep your playing within a four finger/ four fret span. Using open strings in some tunes, interspersed with fretted notes often gives an unwelcome change of tone that won't happen once you play every note fretted.

Answer (score 2):

By doing scales in the lower positions.

What I also find useful is to not stymie your creativity by only knowing a scale two octaves in one position. Learn an octave of a scale on one two and three strings. For instance two string scale and you go the the next string after the fourth note of the scale and learn to go after the fifth as well.

When you have these three main patterns down try combining them. The aim is to have total creative control over where your fingers can go so that the music and the effects you are trying to achieve with your music dictate the positions you play in and not just a mere lack of knowledge.